# How to get files into library directory for iphone device testing

Tags: ios, file, directory, storage

I have tested my app on the ios simulator and using the following code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dictdir = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dict.plist"];
NSLog(dict);
```

I found the path in which to save my file, `dict.plist` so that it can be used later by the app.

I am now testing on my device and the place where I am intending to store my `.plist` file is

> var/mobile/Applications/......./Documents/freq.plist

First of all, I know that non-user data is meant to be saved in the library folder, so how do I change my code so that the path is leading to the `..../library/ directory`?

And how do I actually put my file in this directory? Right now using the 'organizer', I managed to get the file into the app sandbox, but not in a particular folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same code will get the correct path on the device and simulator, that's what it is meant for.  However, if you want to copy it, you have to include it in your bundle, or download it from the internet.  You can't just copy it with the finder.  For copying from the bundle, use the the function [– copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/copyItemAtURL%3atoURL%3aerror%3a).  Downloading is a bit more complicated and is probably better suited for a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just change `NSDocumentDirectory` to `NSLibraryDirectory`